# react CSS opacity transaction with delay but without keyframes

Tags: css, reactjs

So I have an `img` where it starts with `opacity: 100%` and I want to add append another class dynamically so that it changes `opacity` to 30% in 2 seconds but with 5 seconds delay here is what am doing but its not working.

```
.opacity_30 {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: opacity 2s 5s;
}
```

here is the full React code:

```
const logo_classes = classNames('loading-logo', { remove_padding_bottom: !loading, opacity_30: !loading });

<img src={atlas} alt={'atlas logo'} className={logo_classes}/>

.loading-logo {
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding-bottom: 10em;
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
}

.opacity_30 {
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: opacity 2s 5s;
}

.remove_padding_bottom {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    transition: padding-bottom 3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing(or append) className of image tag using states or hooks on triggering any event (like onClick).

Refer this link, it might help you:
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Comment: I don't think that's the issue because `remove_padding_bottom` is working good

Answer (score 0):

You should combine CSS into a single classname or selector, and specify a comma-separated list of transitions.

Apply individually

```
.remove_padding_bottom {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: padding-bottom 3s;
}

.opacity_30 {
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: opacity 2s 5s;
}
```

Apply both transitions simultaneously

```
.opacity_30.remove_padding_bottom {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: opacity 2s 5s, padding-bottom 3s;
}
```

[image: Edit react-css-opacity-transaction-with-delay-but-without-keyframes]